# Authorizate to router panel with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, authorization, router

I am trying to log into my router's panel using python, but the problem is that I have no idea what the protocol for doing that is. I tried using Wireshark to find out, but it just shows just a GET request and a response. I tried logging in to the router and then searching the username and password in the packets, but it didn't find it. (My guess is that it's encrypted)

If anyone could help me with the protocol of logging in to the panel, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. Fllowing the TCP stream gave me the following:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.0.0.138
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Authorization: Basic UG90YXRvOg==
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6

HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="NETGEAR DGN2200v2BEZEQ"
Content-type: text/html

<html>
<head><title>401 Unauthorized</title></head>
<body><h1>401 Unauthorized</h1>
<p>Access to this resource is denied, your client has not supplied the correct authentication.</p></body>
</html>
```

The username and password are encoded in `base64` in the format of `username:password`.